# Android application context configuration doesn't gets updated with the new Locale

Tags: android, locale

I need to access application's localized strings when I'm not using `Context` related classes (Activites, Fragments, Services, Views, etc) in `ViewModel` or custom built classes where I keep all my business logic. For example, posting a `String` to the `UI` with the help of a `LiveData`:

```
toastMessageLiveData.value = buildLastLoginToastMessage()

fun buildLastLoginToastMessage() {
   val lastLoginDiff = (System.currentMillis() - getLastLogin()) / DateUtils.HOURS_IN_MILLIS

   return MyApp.instance.getString(R.string.last_login_txt, lastLoginDiff)
}
```

Now in the `Activity` I'm observing the `LiveData`'s change and I'm showing a Toast message.

This works fine, but **the problem comes if the user changes the application's language**. The layouts are updated and I can see that the new locale's language is used, but the `MyApp.instance.getString(R.string....)` function **is still using the old locale**. If I force-kill the app and I restart it, it's working because the Application's `attachBaseContext` is called again and the new Locale is applied. However, I don't want to force kill the app, I need a solution to update the application's configuration.

Utility function to create or update the `Context`

```
fun buildLocalizedContext(context: Context): Context {
   // From preferences, load the saved Language and Country codes
   val language = getSavedLanguage()
   val country = getSavedCountry()

   // Create the new locale
   val locale = Locale(language, country)
   Locale.setDefault(locale)

   val resources = context.resources
   val configuration = Configuration(resources.configuration)

   // Create a new configration or update the existing one if the API is less than 17
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17) {
      configuration.setLocale(locale)
      return context.createConfigurationContext(configuration)
   } else {
      configuration.locale = locale
      resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, resources.getDisplayMetrics())
   }

   return context
}
```

When the app starts, apply the new Locale

```
class MyApp: Application {
    override fun attachBaseContext(base: Context) {
        super.attachBaseContext(LocaleHelper.instance.buildLocalizedContext(base))
    }
}
```

The `BaseActivity` class which is being used by the other activites:

```
class BaseActivity: AppCompatActivity {
    override fun attachBaseContext(newBase: Context) {
        super.attachBaseContext(LocaleHelper.instance.buildLocalizedContext(newBase))
    }
}
```

This is what I've managed to make so far, however this doesn't work either:

```
fun changeLocale(locale: Locale, app: Application) {
    Locale.setDefault(locale)

    val resources = app.resources
    val configuration = resources.configuration

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17) {
        configuration.setLocale(locale)
    }
    else {
        configuration.locale = locale
        resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, resources.displayMetrics)
    }
}
```

The above code snippet doesn't work, it doesn't changes the Application's Locale, only if I force restart the application.

Comment: "This works fine, but the problem comes if the user changes the application's language" -- apps don't really have languages. Your `setLocale()` approach has always been somewhat of a hack, with spotty support in Android. That being said, is there some solution that involves you not accessing the `Application` directly, but instead via some `ContextWrapper`, where you can change the locale used by the `ContextWrapper`?

Comment: @Commons - One solution would be to send the string resource ids to the `Live Data` and get the strings from the `Activity` or `Fragment`, but this breaks the MVVM principle by moving the business logic to the UI. In the above example, you can see that the business logic of calculating the last login and building the string is made in the `ViewModel`. The problem comes when calling the `MyApp.instance.getString(R.string....)` function inside the `ViewModel`, because the `Locale` inside the `MyApp.instance.configuration.locale` doesn't get updated with the new locale only if I restart the app.

Comment: My point is that rather than calling `MyApp.instance.getString()`, perhaps you can use something other than `MyApp.instance` (such as a `ContextWrapper` around `MyApp.instance`) that is still global in scope but can be replaced at runtime. Or, perhaps the string is created by calling a function, where the caller supplies an `Activity`.

Comment: @CommonsWare - thank you for your quick replies. If you could give me an example how could I use or wrap a `ContextWrapper` around `MyApp.instance` or how could I access an `Activity` from a `ViewModel` without breaking the `MVVM` principle.

Comment: With regards to the latter, `fun buildLastLoginToastMessage(ctxt: Context)` in your above code snippet, where that function is called by your activity or fragment and passes in the activity, and you use `ctxt` for your `getString()` call. In terms of the former, I am merely suggesting an avenue for your own research. Personally, I would never write an app that used `setLocale()`.

Answer (score 2):

As you have experienced, language and several other configurations get applied only to view contexts, not application context.
You seem to be in a strange situation. You may need to revisit your architecture. Generally you want to get the string inside your view and pass it to your ViewModel for processing.
However if you want to make it work the way it is, maybe you can store a WeakReference to a View inside your application object and use that to get localized strings. You can also hold hard reference to the view, but then you would have to be sure to clear it in order to avoid memory leak.
The best solution would be revising your architecture, but this is a ok solution as well.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        (application as App).activity = WeakReference<Activity>(this)
        }
}

class App : Application {
var activity : WeakReference<Activity>? = null
}
```